# Empty log entries on heroku with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, logging, heroku

I am running Symfony2 on a heroku server. Logging works fine except that I get one empty log entry after each log entry from Symfony. Example:

```
2014-01-03T14:29:42.687575+00:00 app[web.1]: [03-Jan-2014 14:29:42 UTC] [2014-01-03 14:29:42]    security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
2014-01-03T14:29:42.687575+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I don't have this problem on my local development environment. Does anybody have a similar problem or a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Since it's from *exactly* the same time stamp, I am guessing that someone, somewhere, it adding a redundant newline.

Comment: Edited my post. Problem does not occur on my development system so I don't think that a new line is appended somewhere in the application code.

Comment: how did you configured your monolog handlers? any nested: type: stream ?